# Enviar E-mails com anexo VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Declarei uma variável para ir passando de linha em linha com um laço de repetição `For` para escrever os e-mails.

Funciona tudo certinho até chegar na parte de anexar o arquivo, ele mostra a imagem de erro abaixo.

Já tentei mudar o caminho várias vezes, mudar o nome dos arquivos, mas nada funciona.

Estrutura base:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
Sub enviar_email()

Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For linha = 2 To 6

    Set Email = objeto_outlook.createitem(0)
    
    Email.display
    
    Email.to = Cells(linha, 1).Value
    
    Email.Subject = "Testando"
    
    Email.Body = Cells(linha, 2).Value & "," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
    & Cells(linha, 3).Value & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
    & "Att," & Chr(10) & "Rafael"
    
    Email.Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\CoParticipacoes\Excel\Participacoes\" & Cells(linha, 2).Value & ".pdf")
    
    Email.send

Next

End Sub
```

Erro:
[image: Dá esse erro]

Answer (score 0):

É necessário ajustar o caminho de busca dos anexos.

Combinar o `ThisWorkbook.Path` com `"C:\CoParticipacoes\Excel\Participacoes\" & Cells(linha, 2).Value & ".pdf"` irá gerar um erro.

`ThisWorkbook.Path` retorna o caminho do próprio arquivo que está executando o VBA. Portanto, supomos que seu arquivo está em: "C:\CoParticipacoes\Excel", ao combinar você receberá o retorno:

```
C:\CoParticipacoes\ExcelC:\CoParticipacoes\Excel\Participacoes\
```

No seu caso em específico, acredito que remover o `ThisWorkbook.Path` deve solucionar.

Utilize as ferramentas de depuração, deve observar esse problema. Ainda, pode fazer um teste assim, para ver um exemplo de como está construindo o local dos arquivos:

```
Sub verCaminho()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\CoParticipacoes\Excel\Participacoes\" & Cells(2, 2).Value & ".pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: FUNCIONOU!!!! Obrigado!!! { <3 }

Comment: Ótimo, feliz em ajudar. Sinaliza como resposta adequada, pode auxiliar mais alguém no futuro.